# Jquery Quiz using Json

Tags: jquery, json

I've found a [script](https://github.com/Matt-Webb/jquery-quiz-using-json) that converts json file into quiz using jquery.

Unfortunately, this script has a bug which is also posted here: [When one infoMode is false the quiz calculation is incorrect. Fix required.](https://github.com/Matt-Webb/jquery-quiz-using-json/issues/1)

Example JSON:

```
{
   "question": "How old is Madonna?",
            "includeInfo": true,
            "info": "Madonna Louise Ciccone is an American singer, songwriter, actress, and businesswoman.",
            "answers": [
                {
                    "answer": "50",
                    "score": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer": "54",
                    "score": 0
                },
                {
                    "answer": "56",
                    "score": 5
                }
            ]
}
```

The problem with this script is if **includeInfo** is set in false, the scoring is not accurate (score is getting equal to zero)

I have here my two JSON, same data but includeInfo is different:

- [[JSFiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/t4p8x02b/28/) includeInfo is false: https://api.myjson.com/bins/3iz33
- [[JSFiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/t4p8x02b/29/) includeInfo is true: https://api.myjson.com/bins/3lbyn

When includeInfo is enabled, the scoring are incrementing. When includeInfo is disabled, score gets only zero.

> Here is the main iteration routine for the quiz which establishes
>   whether or not we are displaying a information box to the user after
>   the question has been answered.

```
 $(data).each(function(index, object) {

     $(object.questions).each(function(index, object) {
         if (infoMode) {
             if (currentQuestion === index) {
                 infoMode = false;
                 complete = false;
                 content = infoHTML(object.info);
             }
         } else {
             if (currentQuestion === index) {
                 complete = false;
                 content = questionHTML(object.question, object.answers);
                 if (object.includeInfo) infoMode = true;
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

Anyone who can fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here you dont save any information about answer when you are in info mode. I couldnt find any distinctive property so i used button's text to catch it.

```
  // ITERATION LOGIC:

    var next = function ($this) {

        if (infoMode) {
            var userAnswer = $($this).serializeArray();
            updateScore(userAnswer);
        } else {
            // you dont save the answer here when user clicks button.
            // maybe : 
            if(($($this).find('button').text() == "next")){
                 var userAnswer = $($this).serializeArray();
                 updateScore(userAnswer);
            } // could be the answer ?               

            currentQuestion += 1;
        }
    };
```

For jsfiddles i updated yours : 
Info Mode is false : https://jsfiddle.net/t4p8x02b/32/
Not a perfect solution but it works

Comment: Can you provide the jsfiddle link?

Comment: added jsfiddle link

Comment: I cant say you would have to try with different values i think , infoMode is swicthing between true and false based on there is a info or question on the view when the infoMode is true, however infoMode is always false when you specify infoMode to false that creates that bug, i just get the counter via "next" button to check it is a question answer and save it as answer

Comment: I'm not encountering any problem except for repeating the quiz. I've added a way to repeat it. But when I click the repeat button, it shows the result / complete variables gets true.

Comment: I've tried to modify global variable but no luck:

        currentQuestion = 0,
        questionCount = 0,
        answerArray = [],
        infoMode = false,
        gotData = false,
        inMemoryData = {},
  score = 0,
  complete = false